# Re-generating source code from LLVM parse tree?

Tags: c++, c, clang, llvm, parse-tree

I'm curious if there are any projects out there that can take an LLVM parse tree and re-generate source code off of it.  I'm particularly thinking of C/C++.

Comment: What is "LLVM parse tree"? Is it Clang AST (then answer is yes, there is clang-based source-to-source tools)? Or is it LLVM IR (then answer is - you can't regenerate exactly same source, but there are/were several projects..)

Answer (score 16):

**If "LLVM parse tree" is AST from clang**

Yes, you can regenerate source from clang's AST. Some references:

- [Basic source-to-source transformation with Clang](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/06/08/basic-source-to-source-transformation-with-clang/) by Eli, 2012
- [Modern source-to-source transformation with Clang and libTooling](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/05/01/modern-source-to-source-transformation-with-clang-and-libtooling/) by Eli, 2014
- [Performing Source-to-Source Transformations with Clang](http://llvm.org/devmtg/2013-04/krzikalla-slides.pdf) (Slides)
- [SoSlang: SOurce-to-Source Clang](http://www.llvm.org/devmtg/2012-11/Keryell_SoSlang.pdf) (Slides)

**If "LLVM parse tree" is LLVM IR**

There were several projects to generate sources from LLVM IR. The first one, the "C back-end" [was dropped in LLVM 3.1](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTE2OTg).

Now there are several projects to generate C from LLVM IR:

- *Resurrected "C back-end"* by Roel Jordans

  [[LLVMdev] [RFC] Resurrecting the C back-end](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/llvmdev/2012-August/052858.html) (Mailing List Post), via cited phoronix news
- "C++ -> LLVM IR -> *Emscripten -> asm.js -> C*" chain

  [Prototype of an LLVM IR => C compiler ("c backend")](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.compilers.llvm.devel/71989), via LLVM Weekly - #15

Comment: I wasn't sure of the exact name, but I'm interested in the representation that's closest to the source without any optimizations or anything applied to it, which makes the AST sound like the representation I want, thanks!

Comment: gct, this is parse tree (Abstract syntax tree) of clang. http://clang.llvm.org/docs/IntroductionToTheClangAST.html http://www.llvm.org/devmtg/2013-04/klimek-slides.pdf‎ http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/Rewriter_8h_source.html